# D00 ボタンスイッチのON/OFF認識

Tags: spresense

D00-GND 間に押しボタンを設け下記コードを実行すると `bStart` は 1 にしかなりません。
また割り込みは数回に一回の確率で実施されます。

ボタンを押すごとに `bStart` が反転してほしいのですが、アドバイスいただけたら幸いです。

```
void changeState() {    // interrupt handler
  bStart = ~bStart;
  Serial.println(bStart);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(intPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(intPin) ,changeState ,FALLING);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

上記のコードに、変数、loop関数を追加してそのまま動かしてみましたが、意図通りに動いてそうです。

```
int bStart = 0;
uint8_t intPin = 0; // D00
void loop() {}
```

D00とGNDをジャンパ線でつないで、bStartがトグルしてシリアルモニタに表示されています。

ここをみると、
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_attachinterrupt

> ピン番号の変化に対して、チャタリング防止用にRTC(32.768kHz) 3サイクル分のノイズフィルタをもっています。
> そのため、急峻なパルス上の信号変化に対しては割り込みを取得できないことがあります。

とあるので信号変化が速いからといった理由があるのかもしれませんね。

Comment: Kzzさん　アドバイスありがとうございます。チャタリング防止が入っているのですね。ゆっくりのボタン操作でもbStartは０にならず。割り込みではなくif文で実行すると意図する動きができました。　とはいえ割り込み関数便利そうなのでもうすこしトライ＆エラーがんばってみます。